# Servlet init method override necessary

Tags: java, servlets, overriding, init

In a Servlet, I send initialization data through web.xml's init param tags. Why do I need to override init method to read the parameters, I can retrieve the values through `getServletConfig().getInitParameter("someName")` in my `doGet` method !

Also, same with config, I can access the initialization parameters with this method : `request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("xyz");`

Why would I need to override the init method, and make sure the superclass config object is set as well etc etc?

Comment: It's just the way they designed it . In hindsight it doesn't appear to be necessary, unless they were planning on people using `ServletConfig` wrappers or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used for init resources or fields servlet, because servlet init which caused only at a time when the servlet is loaded and unloaded ( this rarely happens ). It add some independence  in your code from values parameters and you can change your parameter with out changes in code also if you override init-method your init servlet only one time and not do it everytime when someone send request to your servlet

Answer (score 0):

The init method that you override is not for setting of init parameters, this is done by the method init(ServletConfig config) in the superclass which calls your init method, and is called by the container -

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
   this.config = config;
   this.init();
}
```

There is also no point in calling the init method of the superclass, as it is empty -

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

}
```

You would override the init method if you wanted to do some other code required before you first request.  For example - creating a database connection, setting up some logging details etc.  If this doesn't apply to your code, you can ignore it.